# make columns with left join query

Tags: php, mysql, join

Well, I have two tables in mysql like this:

```
TABLE 1 - users
-------------
id | username | user_data
1  | George   | user_data
2  | John     | user_data


TABLE 2 - services
-------------
id | id_user | service_name | service_data
1  | 1       | lunch        | whatever
2  | 1       | dinner       | …
3  | 2       | lunch        | …
```

Well, with this if I make a query with Left Join like this:

```
SELECT username, service_name
FROM users
LEFT JOIN services ON users.id = services.id_user
WHERE 1
```

I got this:

```
username | service
George   | lunch
George   | dinner
John     | lunch
```

But I need to print to manage data in excel a grid like this:

```
username | service_1 | service_2
George   | lunch     | dinner
John     | lunch
```

I have a lot of rows of users and services and it is not possible make a query asking for services for each user.

Any idea to make this with only one query or any trick in PHP?

Comment: How many types of service are there?  Only lunch and dinner, or something else?

Comment: Hi Tim, the number of services are totally dinamically, can be 5 or null...

Answer (score 1):

You could use GROUP_CONCAT, but note that this doesn't return the service names in separate columns, but just one column instead. For example:

```
SELECT username, GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(services.service_name, 'NA')) AS user_services
FROM users
LEFT JOIN services
    ON users.id = services.id_user
GROUP BY users.id;
```

will return:
[image]

I've created this sqlfiddle:

## SQLFiddle

Comment: What is nice about this solution is it can handle any number of services gracefully.

Comment: In any case I would need null values as well to keep all columns in order

Comment: @JonayGalvánSánchez Please elaborate

Comment: First the all, this problem it is just a sample to explain my real problem. The real problem adds a lot of tables, fields, more joins.

The services have (or not) attributes in other table.

The late motive is print a result to export in CSV like this:

username | t-shirt | size    | food_service | companions
user_1      | yes    | XL      | yes                | 1
user_2      | no      | NULL | yes                | 2
user_3      | yes    | NULL | yes                | 2

Comment: @JonayGalvánSánchez You really have to be more clear, preferably create a fiddle with representative data. Otherwise people won't be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a table pivot issue, maybe not work but try it:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN s.service_data = ''',
      service_data,
      ''' THEN s.service_name ELSE '''' END) AS service_',
      @rowno := @rowno + 1
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT service_data FROM services) t1
JOIN (SELECT @rowno := 0) t2;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT u.username, ',
                  @sql,
                  ' FROM services s
                    JOIN users u ON s.id_user = u.id
                    GROUP BY u.id');
-- SELECT @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[<kbd>SQLFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/daff7/9)

Comment: Hi 10086! your query outputs an empty result with zero errors. Can you explain your query please?

Comment: Did you check the demo in my answer? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/daff7/9, it has results like your question.

Comment: Yep, I executed both querys (creation and select) in my database but return an empty result…

Answer (score 0):

First the all, this problem it is just a sample to explain my real problem. The real problem adds a lot of tables, fields, more joins. The services have (or not) attributes in other table.

The late motive is print a result to export in CSV like this: 
username | t-shirt | size | food_service | companions 
user_1   | yes     | XL   | yes          | 1 
user_2   | no      | NULL | yes          | 2 
user_3   | yes     | NULL | yes          | 2